# python - return next(iterator) with potencial error or None

Tags: python, one-liner

Is there any option to write one liner for something like it:

```
def my_func(some_iter):
    return next('yes' for x in some_iter if x%2 == 0) or None

some_list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
some_list2 = [1, 7, 3, 5]
print(my_func(some_list1)) # should return 'yes'
print(my_func(some_list2)) # should return none
```

so it should iterate over thing until it finds matching option and if there is no matching option then it should return None

Comment: [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with default: `next((... for ... if ...), None)`

Comment: You could also do `'yes' if any(x%2 == 0 for x in some_iter) else None`.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: `(None, "yes")[any(not x%2 for x in some_iter)]` is even less verbose :) and not much more expensive in this case.